# What is a pandas approach to counting text that matches condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, boolean-operations

What are some pandas approaches to being able to count rows where multiple conditions are met?

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : ["1","2","3","4"],
                    'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                    'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
                    'D' : np.array([3] * 4,dtype='int32'),
                    'E' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"]),
                    'F' : 'foo' })
df
```

I am demonstrating the below as a way to count a single condition:

```
print ("Sum for 1 and 3:",(df['A']=="1").sum(),"records")
```

What are some ways to count both "1" and "3"?

In the above example, I would expect an output of *Sum for 1 and 3:* ***2 records***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case you can use `in1d`, which check appartenance :

```
np.in1d(df["A"],["1","3"]).sum()
```

This is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
print ("Sum for 1 and 3:",((df['A']=="1") | (df['A']=="3")).sum(),"records")
('Sum for 1 and 3:', 2, 'records')
```

Or use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `|` (`or`):

```
print ("Sum for 1 and 3:",(df['A'].str.contains("1|3")).sum(),"records")
('Sum for 1 and 3:', 2, 'records')
```

Faster approach use [`np.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
print ("Sum for 1 and 3:",np.sum(df['A'].str.contains("1|3")),"records")
('Sum for 1 and 3:', 2, 'records')
```